# Downloading From Amazon S3 Bucket with a file name

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file from amazon s3 but with a different name. i.e. not the name of the stored file which has timestamps attached_to_it.
But If I download it from `s3.getObject`

```
  s3.getObject({
    Key: fileKey,
    Bucket: `/${albumBucketName}`,
    //ResponseContentDisposition: `attachment; filename="${fileKey}"`,
    //ResponseContentType: "audio/wav"
  }, function (
    err,
    data
  ) {
   ....
});
```

it will not let the download being handled by browser. so, I will not get download progress in general. I dont want to handle the download progress in my app. I want it to download from browser. 
I didn't go with URL approach because it won't let me specify a name for the file being downloaded.

EDIT:
there is a solution for this, which is giving anchor tags download attribute specifying the file name in it. but it wont work in ios safari. but still I dont want to loose accessibility of the feature for some user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part is on the right track:

```
ResponseContentDisposition: `attachment; filename="${desired_filename_here}"`,
```

...but instead of `s3.getObject()`, you need [`s3.getSignedUrl()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property).  This generates a URL that contains embedded credentials, in a format that allows access to this one object but does not make the credentials reusable for any other purpose.  Pass this URL to the browser and the file will be downloaded with the desired name.

You can use `ResponseContentDisposition` with `s3.getSignedUrl()`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I had to use it with callback, s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", params, (err, url) => { })